# Is it wrong to wear a ring on the index and middle finger for men?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Assalamualaikum,

I read that Allah's messenger (pbuh) forbade men from wearing rings on their index and middle finger. Is this accurate?

Jzk

Answer (score 1):

Yes there exists a hadith which forbids wearing a ring on the middle and finger next to it. It is as follows:

> قال علي نهاني رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم أن أتختم في إصبعي هذه أو هذه قال فأومأ إلى الوسطى والتي تليها
>
> Ali said:
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) forbade me that I should wear a ring in this and that finger of mine, and he pointed to the middle finger and the next one.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2078g)</sup>

Hence various jurists have ruled that for men it is makruh to wear a ring in these fingers, or that it is preferable to wear it on the little finger. And some have even said that a ring should only be worn on the little finger of the left hand by men since that is the place where the Prophet ﷺ wore it (see [hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2095)).

**Ref:**  [Mawsoo‘ah al-Fiqhiyyah](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/6326)  and [islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/139540/) (english)

Answer (score -2):

AFAK, only wearing gold for men is restricted. The position of a silver ring or any other material is not important.