# Why is it prohibited to wear ring on index and middle finger?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad

Assalamualaikum, I have heard that wearing a ring on index and middle finger is prohibited  in islam for men. The question is why is it prohibited, and if i still wear it on my index finger, then am I committing a sin?

Comment: See https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75008/

Comment: I read that, but its not stated why is it prohibited, and is it a sin ir makruh if someone does it